# RcppExports.R not being modified

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, roxygen2

I am building an R package with `Rcpp`. I have included `roxygen2` style comments in the source cpp file but those comments are not reflected in `R/RcppExports.R` and `src/RcppExports.cpp` after building the package and `devtools::document()`.

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

//' @title Linearc
//' @description Computes the linear regression coefficient estimates 
(ridge-penalization and weights, optional)
//' @param X matrix
//' @param y matrix
//' @param lam optional tuning parameter for ridge regularization term. 
Defaults to 'lam = 0'
//' @param weights optional vector of weights for weighted least squares
//' @param intercept add column of ones if not already present. Defaults to 
TRUE
//' @param kernel use linear kernel to compute ridge regression 
coefficeients. Defaults to true when p >> n
//' @return returns the coefficient estimates
//' @export
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::export]]
List linearrc(const arma::mat& X, const arma::colvec& y, double lam = 0, 
arma::colvec weights = 0, bool intercept = true, bool kernel = false) {
...
```

#### No modifications in `R/RcppExports.R`:

```
# Generated by using Rcpp::compileAttributes() -> do not edit by hand
# Generator token: 10BE3573-1514-4C36-9D1C-5A225CD40393

linearrc <- function(X, y, lam = 0, weights = 0L, intercept = TRUE, kernel = 
FALSE) {
    .Call('statr_linearrc', PACKAGE = 'statr', X, y, lam, weights, intercept, 
kernel)
}
```

#### No modifications in `src/RcppExports.cpp`:

```
// Generated by using Rcpp::compileAttributes() -> do not edit by hand
// Generator token: 10BE3573-1514-4C36-9D1C-5A225CD40393

#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// linearrc
List linearrc(const arma::mat& X, const arma::colvec& y, double lam, 
arma::colvec weights, bool intercept, bool kernel);
RcppExport SEXP statr_linearrc(SEXP XSEXP, SEXP ySEXP, SEXP lamSEXP, SEXP 
weightsSEXP, SEXP interceptSEXP, SEXP kernelSEXP) {
BEGIN_RCPP
    Rcpp::RObject rcpp_result_gen;
    Rcpp::RNGScope rcpp_rngScope_gen;
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< const arma::mat& >::type X(XSEXP);
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< const arma::colvec& >::type y(ySEXP);
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< double >::type lam(lamSEXP);
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< arma::colvec >::type weights(weightsSEXP);
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< bool >::type intercept(interceptSEXP);
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< bool >::type kernel(kernelSEXP);
    rcpp_result_gen = Rcpp::wrap(linearrc(X, y, lam, weights, intercept, 
kernel));
    return rcpp_result_gen;
END_RCPP
}
```

I have included `#' @useDynLib <pkg-name>` and `#' @importFrom Rcpp sourceCpp` in a random .R file in the package. I am using latest version of Rstudio and Roxygen2.

Also, the `linearrc` function does not appear in the NAMESPACE in the form `export(linearrc)` either...

Thanks!

Comment: If you read the documentation it will introduce to a friendly function called `compileAttributes()`.  Try it.

Comment: I think `// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]` immediately after the comments is causing the issue. This can be removed.

Comment: Ah what a dumb mistake. That was it -- thanks @coatless !